# Strange behavior in Visual Studio XAML designer with subclass of Window with generics from another project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm

I'm facing a strange glitch in XAML designer in Visual Studio 2022. I'm trying to create a base class for my windows, by respecting the MVVM pattern. This base class has a generic argument of type "MyBaseViewModel". Everything works when running the executable, but the designer does not paint the window in some cases (the XAML designer is visible, but my window's content not). This issue only happens when the base generic window class is located in another referenced project of my solution, and it does not occur when the same exact base class is placed in the project where it's used. There are no errors from Visual Studio (not even the "fake" ones in XAML designer).

I have two libraries in my solution: MyUtils, and MyLibrary:

MyUtils

- MyBaseWindow.cs
- MyBaseViewModel.cs

MyLibrary

- Window1.xaml/.cs
- Window1ViewModel.cs
- IWindow1DialogsFactory.cs

Here is the code:

**MyBaseWindow.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyUtils
{
    public class MyBaseWindow<T> : Window where T : BaseViewModel, new()
    {
        private T viewModel;
        public T ViewModel
        {
            get => viewModel;
            protected set => viewModel = value;
        }

        public MyBaseWindow()
        {
            ViewModel = new T();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyBaseViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyUtils
{
    public class MyBaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Window1.xaml**

```
<util:MyBaseWindow x:TypeArguments="local:Window1ViewModel" x:Class="MyLibrary.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyLibrary"
        xmlns:util="clr-namespace:MyUtils;assembly=MyUtils"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="Green">
        
    </Grid>
</util:MyBaseWindow>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public partial class Window1 : IWindow1DialogsFactory
    {
        public Window1() => InitializeComponent();

        public Window1(string arg1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel.Initialize(arg1, this);
        }

        //To be replaced by actual implementations, returning an interface instead of "Window" type...
        public Window MakeChildWindow1() => new Window(); 
        public Window MakeChildWindow2() => new Window();
    }
}
```

**Window1ViewModel**

```
using MyUtils;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class Window1ViewModel : MyBaseViewModel
    {
        private string field1;
        private IWindow1DialogsFactory dialogsFactory;

        public Window1ViewModel()
        {
        }

        public void Initialize(string arg1, IWindow1DialogsFactory dialogsFactory)
        {
            field1 = arg1;
            this.dialogsFactory = dialogsFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

**IWindow1DialogsFactory**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Myibrary
{
    public interface IWindow1DialogsFactory
    {
        Window MakeChildWindow1();
        Window MakeChildWindow2();
        //..
    }
}
```

I tried to copy the exact same "MyBaseWindow" class file (except for an additional "include") in "MyLibrary" project, and when I try to replace the heading "<util:MyBaseWindow " with "<local:MyBaseWindow " in XAML, the window gets painted in designer correctly, why is that so? What is wrong with my approach, and what is preventing the designer from painting the window when the base class is located in "MyUtils" project? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You can explicitly set the XAML designer's design-time DataContext in the Window1.xaml file like

`d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Window1ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`